# Adding input prefix in an admin form

Tags: magento2, forms, uicomponent, crud

I'm trying to build a CRUD module for Magento 2 by using the ui components.
but I need to add a prefix for all my inputs in the form.
So if I add a field called `name` I need the field name to actually be `prefix[name]`.
Using the `Magento\Framework\Data\Form` class to generate my fields worked great with

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create();
$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('prefix_');
$form->setFieldNameSuffix('prefix');
```

But I want to do it via ui component xml.
Here is how my xml looks right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">[namespace]_[module]_[entity]_form.[entity]_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">[namespace]_[module]_[entity]_form.[entity]_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">[Entity] Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">[namespace]_[module]_[entity]_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Edit\Buttons\Back</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Edit\Buttons\Delete</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Edit\Buttons\Reset</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Edit\Buttons\Save</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Edit\Buttons\SaveAndContinue</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="[entity]_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\[Entity]\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">[entity]_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">[entity]_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">[entity]_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="[namespace_module]/[entity]/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="[entity]">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">[Entity] Information</item>
            </item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </argument>
        <field name="[enitity]_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">[entity]</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">[entity]_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">[entity]</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This works nicely, and generates the add/edit form with a single field called `name` but I don't know how to add the prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How can I control dataScope?

If you want to control whole name of POST key (like `prefix[name]`) on Field level then you'll interested in discard autocomposing it.

First of all how it composed? When a Field placed in chain `Form1 > Fieldset1 > Fieldset2 > Field`, then Field gets POST key `Form1[Fieldset1][Fieldset2][Field]`.

If you want to omit Fieldset1 from chain then you configure its `dataScope` as empty sting. Examples:

`Fieldset1.dataScope = ""` -> POST key is `Form1[Fieldset2][Field]`.

`Fieldset1.dataScope = ""`
`Fieldset2.dataScope = ""` -> POST key is `Form1[Field]`.

`Form1.dataScope = "data"`
`Fieldset1.dataScope = ""`
`Fieldset2.dataScope = ""` -> POST key is `Field`.

`Form1.dataScope = "data.prefix"`
`Fieldset1.dataScope = ""`
`Fieldset2.dataScope = ""` -> POST key is `prefix[Field]`.

`Form1.dataScope = "data"`
`Fieldset1.dataScope = ""`
`Fieldset2.dataScope = ""`
`Field.dataScope = "prefix.field2"` -> POST key is `prefix[field2]`.

## What does dataScope affect?

You should remember that `dataScope` is not a *POST key*. It's a keychain from DataProvider object. In xml configuration there is `<dataSource/>` tag. This tag configures who is provider data for form. Client side app produces DataProvider object and link every Field's value with some DataProvider's key. So string `dataScope` just point to some DataProvider's key.

If you want to control Form's POST object it means that you want to control DataProvider's data structure also.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I understand the concept (I think) but I don't understand what code should I use where? Can you show and example with what do I need to change in the ui component and in the DataProvider ?

Comment: If i need to set data to field2 in form create new . How can i do it? I can't find anywhere do that. Try to set data in Provider but it not works. Is there anyway to access to form data such as $formdata[field]